# Função retornando None quando termina

Tags: python-3.x, recursão

A função, quando desfaz a recursividade, retorna `None`, e não estou sabendo o porquê.

```
def fat(n):
  if n == 0 or n == 1:
    return 1
  else:
    return n * fat(n - 1)


def superfat (n, x = 1):
   if n > 0:
      x*=fat(n)
      n-=1
      return superfat(n, x)

número = int(input("Digite um número para descobrir o seu superfatorial: "))
print("O fatorial de {} é {}.".format(número, superfat(número)))
```

Comment: Na função `superfat`, chegará o ponto em que `n` será 0. Qual o valor que deveria ser retornado nesse caso? Como você não colocou, ele será `None`.

Answer (score 1):

Veja o seu código.

```
def superfat (n, x = 1):
    if n > 0:
        x*=fat(n)
        n-=1
        return superfat(n, x)
```

Quando `n > 0`, o seguinte trecho será executado:

```
x*=fat(n)
n-=1
return superfat(n, x)
```

Mas e quando `n <= 0`, o que será executado?

Nada!

Você deve escrever o que deve ser retornando quando aquele `if` for falso.

Por exemplo...

```
def superfat (n, x = 1):
    if n > 0:
        x*=fat(n)
        n-=1
        return superfat(n, x)
    return 1
```

Neste caso, eu iria reescrever para:

```
def superfat (n, x = 1):
    if n <= 0:
        return 1

    x*=fat(n)
    n-=1
    return superfat(n, x)
```

Pois fica mais claro o momento em que a recursão acaba (mas isso é questão de preferência).